# preload Cloud Firestore via json?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I see no way in the Cloud Firestore database interface in my dashboard to (say) import a bunch of "documents" into a collection via JSON (or similar). Am I missing something? I have no problem creating some sideband code in Go to preload/refresh the database. Is this the intended method?

Historically I've done this with SQL files - this is my first foray into NoSQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option in the Firebase console to import a JSON into Firestore.

But you **can** use the `gcloud` command line tool to both export and import data with Firestore. For a step-by-step walkthrough, see the documentation on [exporting and importing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import).

A quick search also gave me this [`firestore-backup-restore` npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-backup-restore). While I'm not sure how up to date it is, its code might be a good starting point in case you need something more custom than what the `gcloud` CLI gives you.

Alternatively you can of course read the JSON yourself, and call the Firestore API to write the documents. That's pretty much what both tools above do under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `gcloud`. I will still roll my own side-loading utility as a teaching tool, but the console works well, too.